# Launching DroolsTest aka "Hello World" failure

Tags: eclipse, drools

Win7/Eclipse Kepler/Drools 5.5

Installed Drools IDE plugins and pointed IDE to Drools install for runtime.

Repro steps:
1. In Eclipse, File->New->Drools Project
2. Checkmark "Add a sample Hello World rule file..."
3. Checkmark "Add a sample Java class for loading and executing Hello World rules."
4. Checkmark "Use default Drools Runtime"
5. Navigate to "DroolsTest.java" and right-click "main". Select "Debug"->"Drools Application"

An internal error occurred during: "Launching DroolsTest (1)".
org/drools/eclipse/launching/DroolsVMDebugger.renderProcessLabel([Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;

Tried the following solutions:
6. In the  “VM arguments” field, enter: -Ddrools.compiler=JANINO
7. Click on Help->Update Software to get an updated JDT Core

Any ideas on how to get this working?

Rant: Really? Hello world fails? This has got to be number 1 on how the list of how to convince people not to use your open source software.

Answer (score 4):

I had a hunch that the problem might be version-incompatibility. I installed the drools plugin on Juno and it worked out of the box.

Comment: Thanks. You save me :) I downloaded the latest Eclipse oxygen, but cannot work. Then I used the Juno, it works.